# Ripple effect of TextView gets stuck on long click, when selection is used

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, multipleselection, ripple-effect

I recently refactored my App to use the jetpack navigation. On my MainActivity, I had a ViewPager containing 3 fragments with 1 recyclerview each. I therefore moved the ViewPager from the Activity to a new Fragment. Everything works when it comes to the functionality itself, but a new issue arose which really bugs me: When I select an item on the recyclerview with a long press, the ripple effect gets stuck and stays there, as if I'm still pressing the item, which I don't. Here is a picture of a selected item. As it can be seen, the ripple effect stays active on the TextView.

[image: Here is a picture of a selected item]

When I unselect the Item, the ripple effect also stays active:
[image]

The selection itself is handled with the android SelectionTracker. The TextView has the background set to `background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`. The whole ViewItem has the background set to `android:background="@drawable/bg_multi_selection`, whereas the bg_multi_selection file looks as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:drawable="@color/secondaryLightColor" android:state_activated="true" />
         <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
   </selector>
```

What could be the issue of that? This is especially weird, as the problem did not exist, when the ViewPager with its fragments was contained inside the Activity, and not a Fragment. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works for me. So for anyone interested, I did the following:

In the recyclerviewadapter in the onBindViewHolder() method I check if the element is selected and additionally set the background color and background resource of the TextView programmatically.

```
if (elementIsSelected) {
                viewHolder.viewBinding.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.transparent, context.theme))
            } else {
                val outValue = TypedValue()
                context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true)
                viewHolder.viewBinding.itemTextView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId)
            }
```

whereas I definied the color to be transparent, i.e. #00000000

It's odd that this problem occurs only on some devices, so I'm not sure if the "real" problem lies somewhere else, but at least that's how I fixed it. Hope that might be helpful for someone else.